# Using Ehcache API in Hibernate

Tags: ehcache

Using Ehcache API How can we write our own data cache in Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

This is really two questions:

1. Can I write my own data cache?  Of course, but it's hard to see why.  How will yours be different or better than EhCache?
2. How can I wire my own data cache into Hibernate?  Sorry, I don't know.  I'd use EhCache or Terracotta or something else that exists.